# How to pass django authtoken using ajax

Tags: django-rest-framework

How to pass djangorest authtoken from AJAX request
I tried following code.but not working

```
$({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'menu/menu/,
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization ", "Token " + token);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try serialize your authtoken

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/menu/menu/",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        sucess: function() { //do something },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain:false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Noo.I m talking about AuthToken not about csrf token.refer https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/